# im trying to make a thread pool code but my for loop only work once

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

i've tried to use for loop for few time. it work smooth if im using for ... in range() but it always work only once if im using for ... in list

here's the code

```
def queue_time(customers, n):
    a = 0
    ab =[]
    if n == 1:
        return sum(customers)
    if n > len(customers):
        return max(customers)
    
    for x in customers:
        while a<n:
            ab.append(x)
            a += 1
        for c in ab: 
            if c == min(ab):
                c = min(ab) + x  
    return ab
```

im trying to make a simple code for thread pool but it seems like my code suck but idk where it is(im newbie BTW)

Comment: What are `customers`?

Comment: customers is a list that contain time(integer), n is the amount of the thread

Comment: Where is your thread-related code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.